# Reading a bunch of files and writing to a socket (asynchronously) in android gives OutofMemoryError exception

Tags: java, android

In my android application I read a bunch of files in a chunk of 64KiB and write it to a socket. The write to socket is async and I do not have a control over it, neither it provides a callback function.

If I read large files, I get OOM exception as socket is still working on parsing the bytes and sending them over the network.

For reference the code looks like below:

```
byte[] chunk = new byte[64 * 1024];
int read;
while ((read = fis.read(chunk)) != -1) {
  // Async call
  socket.write(chunk);
  chunk = new byte[64 * 1024];
}
```

Is there any design pattern I can follow to overcome this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A TCP packet can only hold 1.5 - 9 KB depending on the MTU. So if you use a 8 KB buffer it probably won't make any difference.

The cause of your problem is that you are creating copies of the array..

```
while ((read = fis.read(chunk)) != -1) {
  socket.write(chunk, 0, read); // no need to make this asynchronous.
}
```

The OSes send TCP buffer is usually 64 KB and that sends the data asynchronously already. Unless you have infiniband or 40 GigE, its unlikely to help.  Copying the data in a buffer is likely to make it slower.

Comment: I don't know much about sockets. The one I am using is a WebSocket library. I am making a copy of array as the same variable is written again and used by socket in parallel.

Comment: It appears you are trying to use a complicated solution when a simpler is likely to be better (and more likely to work).  You can't use a single socket in parallel as it is a continuous stream, if it were not you couldn't be sure data is received in the order it is sent (as it is for UDP)

Comment: I understand that a socket can't write in parallel and it behaves the same here. In this situation reading a file is faster than writing it to a socket which causes OOM exception.

Comment: Indeed. Which is why I am wondering why you are trying to use asynchronous communication when it can only make it slower than regular sockets and fails.